# Is there a way to display a model from multiple camera angles in Autodesk Forge Viewer without loading the model multiple times?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We would like to use the Autodesk Forge Viewer to implement a screen in which you can see the loaded model(s) from multiple camera angles. For example, one view in which the model is displayed from a perspective and another view in which we display the model from the top in an orthographic camera.
[Mockup with 2 viewer canvases and an example model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHdgK.png)

We already searched the documentation and examples of viewer applications that can be found in the web but did not encounter any hints yet how this could be implemented.
We also implemented a prototype solution by initializing two viewers with the same document URN. This let's us implement what we want but for large models the memory consumption is too high and the WebGL context is likely to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the current Viewer SDK does not provide this capability out-of-the-box but after talking to the engineering team, it might be possible to achieve this using a feature that is currently only available for internal use. We will explore this area and update this answer with the results, so please stay tuned.

Aaand here it is: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/sharing-resources-among-multiple-viewers :)